# How to say "I would like you to know..." but begin with "You, who I would like ..."?

Tags: grammaticality

I would like to say something like "You, who I would like you to know about this". But the second "you" seems wrong. What is the correct way to write this sentence?

Comment: Why don't you want to use "I would like you to know about this"?

Comment: Because thats not how I want to say it. The effect I want it to have is not achieved that way. Aside from that, I am curious how it can be said this way.

Comment: Just remove the second "you". However, I suspect this is still not what you want. What is the desired effect, exactly?

Comment: Maybe something like "you, who I would especially like to be aware of this, ..."

Comment: @siride - you mean just say "You, who I would like to know about this". Is that right? It sounds more like I want to know about something, rather than wanting the other person to know about it.

Comment: *You, whom I would like to inform...*

Comment: Tinfoil Hat's is elegant; the uglier alternative is to add a noun, such as *You, person I want to know about this.* ("I would like to know" seems unnecessarily long-winded and vague compared to something like "should know".)

Comment: If you are not careful, such a structure could result in an incomplete sentence. Including the verb for *you* can help: *You, alone, are best to know...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say "I would like you to know about this." Therefore, you can say "You, whom I would like to know about this, . . ." Note that the relative pronoun "whom" is in the object case because it replaces "you" in the first sentence, which is in the object case. (In both sentences, it is the DO of "like".)

Others will analyze this sentence differently, of course, but this is one possibility.

Comment: So this is correct? - "To you, whom I want to know how I feel"

Comment: Well, it's not a complete sentence, but otherwise yes, "I want you to know how I feel" can be converted into a relative clause as what you wrote. Note that the messiness with the infinitive phrase and the nominal clause will make this sound unnatural to many people, so I'd recommend rephrasing it if possible, but technically it works.

Comment: Thanks. Its a dedication, so I guess that takes care of the incomplete sentence problem. What do you thin about the other answer who is basically using the same sentence formation but using 'who' instead of 'whom'?

Comment: @Gadam I would consider it to be incorrect according to standard rules of English grammar, because "who" functions as the DO of "like" and should thus be in the objective case ("whom"). Of course, "who" is often used colloquially in such situations, so in a casual context I wouldn't worry about it. (BTW, many descriptivists are fine with using "who" in the objective case; by that standard it wouldn't be wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an example.

> I would like you to know the truth. You are going to be shocked.

transforms to

> You, who I would like to know the truth, are going to be shocked.

Note the absence of the second "you". Putting a second "you" is incorrect.

The sentence above is grammatically correct but it is horrible style, convoluted and confusing. Don't do it.

Comment: Thanks. Style is subjective so what is good for you might be bad for others. I am more concerned about the technical correctness which you confirmed. Can we also use 'Whom' instead of 'who' as the other answers suggested?